# Why can't Spark find the classes in this Jar?

Tags: java, maven, jar, apache-spark

I am new to spark. I am trying to compile and run a spark application that requires classes from an (external) jar file on my local machine. If I open the jar (on ~/Desktop) I can see the missing class in the local jar but when I run spark I get

```
NoClassDefFoundError: edu/stanford/nlp/ie/AbstractSequenceClassifier
```

I add the jar to the spark context like this

```
String[] jars = {"/home/pathto/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar"};
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application").setJars(jars);
```

Then I try to run a submit script like this

```
/home/pathto/Downloads/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit \
  --class "SimpleApp" \
  --master local[4] \
  target/simple-project-1.0.jar \
  --jars local[4] /home/abe/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar
```

and hit the NoClassDefFoundError.

I get that this means that the worker threads can't find the class from the jar. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried different syntaxes for the last line (below) but none works.

```
  --addJars local[4] /home/abe/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar
  --addJars local:/home/abe/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar
  --addJars local:/home/abe/Desktop/stanford-corenlp-3.5.0.jar
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Do you also get a `ClassNotFoundException`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5756989/3318517

Comment: @DanielDarabos yes. I am getting that exception

Comment: As a work around I packaged the dependencies into the main app jar and deployed that with Maven. That got it working. But the question is still open.

Comment: I am confused you had any trouble finding jars in --master local[4] mode, I thought that bypassed all the jar issues. When I develop a program I have never gotten into "can't find jars" type of error until I run in standalone cluster mode.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? [I have the same right now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400727/noclassdeffounderror-on-nodes-how-to-distribute-dependencies-to-all-nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the jar file location using `file:/path/to/jar/jarfile.jar/`.  Using `local:` means that the jar file has to already exist in the specified location on each worker node.  For more information, see the "Advanced Dependency Management" section of the [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/submitting-applications.html) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the complete path of your main class 
For ex. : com.package.MyMainClass

./bin/spark-submit --class com.MyMainClass /home/hadoop/Documents/Harish/HelloSpark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -config /home/hadoop/Documents/Harish/Config.properties

This is what I used....also check for permissions on linux machine.